# Trap double-click from WebBrowser in VB6

Tags: vb6, webbrowser-control, double-click

In VB6, I am using a WebBrowser form to display all files and subfolders as *medium-size* icons in the style of Windows Explorer. On the form, I display a count of all files in the main folder and all subfolders.

When you double-click one of the subfolders, WebBrowser displays the contents of the subfolder in *small-size* icons.  I want to trap the double-click so I can trigger several actions - a form refresh, display as *medium-size icons* and count the number of files in the selected subfolder.

Any suggestions?

Comment: As a guess you can try to process double-click at HTML side with some js and then trigger navigation to the URL related to your clicked icon. At VB side you can subscribe to BeforeNavigate2/NavigateComplete2 events and catch that action this way you'll understand that double-click happened.